# how to assign a $? value to a global variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I just want to assign a `$?` value to a global variable like in below script

```
samplefunction() {
 basecost_flag=0

if [ "$basecost_flag" -eq 0 ]; then
    basecost_flag=1;
fi
return $basecost_flag
}

var=$(samplefunction)

function_return_val=$?
echo "$functin_return_val"
```

i want to store `function_return_val` as 1 but When i execute above code it's not printing any thing

Comment: Maybe just a typo? It is written `echo "$functin_return_val"` instead of `echo "$function_return_val"`.

Comment: I just want store the 'function_return_val' as function return statement val.

Comment: The variable `functin_return_val` as you wrote in the code was **not** initialized (look at the name, the `o` is missing).

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, now its working fine and it's my bad

Comment: Looks like you could benefit from `set -u`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
echo "$functin_return_val"
```

with

```
echo "$function_return_val"
```